# What functions from Kernel32.dll are supported on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, filesystems

I am seeking a documentation on List of functions from Kernel32.dll which are supported on Mono. I searched a a lot but gained nothing. My particular interest are File and directory enumeration function like FindFirstFile(...) etc. Is there any way to use such inter-oped code in Mono? What will be DllMap entry in such case for Mono?

Thanks,
Omkar

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the classes and methods in System.IO for that stuff, instead of going with the non portable P/Invoke route.